# How do you get value of form using angular javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

been trying to get the value of form using angular js on form submit.
someone help me what to do. I am new to angular JS.

```
<div id="content" ng-app="TryApp" ng-controller="AppController" ng- submit="submit()">  

<input type="text" placeholder="first name" name='name' ng-  model="user.Name"/>
<br>
<input type="text" placeholder="email address" name="name" ng-model="user.email"/>
<br>
<input type="text" placeholder="age" name="age" ng-model="user.age"/>
<br>
```

script.

```
App.controller('AppController', function ($scope){

)}
```

Comment: You need a `<form>` to apply `ng-submit` to. Also give form a name for your validation object

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```js
var app = angular.module('TryApp', [], function() {})

app.controller('AppController', function($scope) {
  $scope.user = {};
  $scope.submit = function() {
    //here $scope.user will have all the 3 properties
    alert(JSON.stringify($scope.user));
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div id="content" ng-app="TryApp" ng-controller="AppController">
  <form ng-submit="submit()">
    <input type="text" placeholder="first name" name='name' ng-model="user.Name" />
    <br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="email address" name="name" ng-model="user.email" />
    <br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="age" name="age" ng-model="user.age" />
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    <p>{{user | json }}</p>
  </form>
</div>
```

Note: for submit handler to work, you need a form and a submit button as shown above